# how to load a large numpy (.npy) file

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, google-colaboratory, ram

I am wondering how to load the Endo Mondo dataset found here: https://sites.google.com/eng.ucsd.edu/fitrec-project/home

The file is a 6.0 gb npy file

I am trying to load it into a colab pro instance.

I have tried using the large ram instance with gpu and on jax numpy. I imagine theres a more obvious problem holding me up.

Very simple issue can't believe its stumping me.

Best,

Aidan

Comment: What's the issue that you are facing?

Comment: the colab instance crashes and runs out of ram thanks for the speedy response

Comment: I see, please check if the answer works for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to partially read large numpy file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727412/efficient-way-to-partially-read-large-numpy-file)

Comment: this does not answer the question, using mem map causes this error: ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mmap_mode=True` in [`np.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) argument:

```
>>> arr = np.load('file.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

Comment: im following the solution but it did not work! ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.

Comment: any thoughts I still cant fix it?

Comment: I see, the reason it can't be memory-mapped is because there are something other than numbers in the file. In that case, I am not really sure what more you could do with an `.npy`.