# How to read few npy files memory-efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, file, numpy-ndarray

I have 5 NPy files (2,2GB each), each of them stores a list of 200k elements. One element is a dictionary which has 5 fields (among them two lists of 500 elements, 4 lists of 50 elements, all elements are float numbers).

I want to load all of them into one variable, but after reading the first file, the usage of RAM memory increases that much that the program is being killed by the system. I'm using the following code:

```
np_new_load = lambda *a, **k: np.load(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)

filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(DATA_MODEL_NON_UNIFORM_1_MLN) if name.find('.npy')]
first_file_path = os.path.join(DATA_MODEL_NON_UNIFORM_1_MLN, filenames[0])
data = np_new_load(first_file_path)
for filename in filenames[1:]:
    file_path = os.path.join(DATA_MODEL_NON_UNIFORM_1_MLN, filename)
    array = np_new_load(file_path,  mmap_mode='r')
    data = np.concatenate((data, array), axis=0)
    del array
return data
```

What should I change to read all values from all files? Should I separate some of dictionary fields to different files? Maybe change a file format?

Earlier I was working on Json's files but the same issue was there. I have to add that my PC doesn't have any GPU card that could be used to speed up operations.

Comment: [Efficient way to partially read large numpy file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727412/efficient-way-to-partially-read-large-numpy-file)

Comment: I read it but I got an error ("Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.",) @IzaakCornelis

Comment: It seems like there's a custom data type in your npy file, is there a way around that? e.g. only saving field members, and reconstruct the object from its fields?

Comment: in single file there is a list of dictionaries with 6 fields, so also I was considering to concatenate all values of specific field from all files into one file (e.g. I have a dict with keys "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" and I want to separately store "a" values in one file), but I don't know if it would work or there still be an issue

Comment: Repeated concatenates in a loop is not efficient;  too much copying into the new array.  Collecting `data` in  a list, and doing one `concatenate` at the end is better.  But I don't think it solves your memory issue.  Sounds like one file loads as an object dtype array, and there might not be enough memory to hold more than one at a time.  Load one file and tell us about the result - shape, dtype, etc

Comment: You can't chsnge how the `npy` is loaded, but you may be able extract the values you really need, and accumulate just those. It's hard to help without a [mcve], which is hard to provide in the case of large 'object' dtype array files.

Comment: I resolved my issue by saving my data in many files